# Adobe Illustrator CS6 - Curved Guides? - How to reverse 'Make Guides'

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

So, I decided to try freehanding a design, and I used the pencil tool. Then I was working with it. <del>But somewhere along the line, my curve turned into a beizer guide, which I don't want and will probably never need.</del> Then, by accident, I right-clicked and hit "Make Guides" without realizing it.

It's already been saved and closed, so there's no way I can undo it. How can I turn it back into a path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure guides aren't locked: **View** → **Guides** → **Lock Guides**

[image: Lock Guides]

Select the guide, right click on it, **Release Guides** *OR* you can do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> (Windows)

[image: Release Guides]

Comment: Thanks so much. I re-made it anyway, since it was simple, but in the future this'll be really helpful to know!